# QAction::setAccel(QString) not available from Qt 4?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui, qt3, qaction

Following this documentation:

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq14-actioneditor.html

I figured that out there is no `QAction::setAccel(QString)` method anymore.

How can one modify the `QAction` accel other than using QtCreator? I need to change them runtime.

The documentation does not even seem to mention this method anymore here:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the documentation does contain this [under the qt3support section](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction-qt3.html):

> The following class members are part of the Qt 3 support layer. They are provided to help you port old code to Qt 4. We advise against using them in new code.

You could still use it with some qmake modification as follows:

```
QT += qt3support
```

But as [the documentation writes](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qaction-qt3.html#setAccel):

> void QAction::setAccel ( const QKeySequence & shortcut )
>
> Use setShortcut() instead.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `QAction::setAccel(QString)` was renamed to `setShortcut`.